# Can my vps provider see that I'm using a vpn service on my vps?

Tags: vpn, firewall, vps

If so can I know, how do they do it? I contacted the CS and they said that they use something like NextGen firewall and AI to detect these actions. I want to know more about this but cant seem to find resources.

Comment: They can listen to your network traffic on their infrastructure. That's basically it.

Comment: Is it against the terms of use to connect your VPS to a VPN? Hosts have a broad range of vision into the VMs running on their systems. It is essentially physical access and control. Depending on how they set things up though, they may market based on more privacy and so could theoretically not be inspecting things so closely, but you'd have to trust them on this. Are you concerned they'll learn your breaking their rules, or just want to know for curiosity sake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can see that traffic is happening and where it comes from and goes to. Source and destination information is absolutely necessary for two way communication.

That said they will only see packets addressed to your VPN provider. They will not see anything more than that. Your traffic to other sites will be packed up and encrypted within the tunnel that goes to your VPN provider.

A substantial amount of data coming to or from particular machines isn't uncommon, but it would be unusual to see modern machines which rely on automatic updates, time servers and all sorts of other online connections to communicate *exclusively* with one other computer and have zero traffic to other places. It is a clear sign of a locked down or VPN equipped machine.

There are many "IP lookup" systems that they could be using to determine where all that traffic is going to and identify which VPN provider you are using.